# How do I convert a Document into a String in Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using the [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service). After certain manipulations over a [Document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/document) object, I want to return it as a single String.

I read the XML as a string, turn it into a Document object using the XmlService, delete some nodes and now I want it to be a String again to return it as a result of a function in a spreadsheet. How do I do that? I've searched the documentation to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options: `getPrettyFormat` and `getRawFormat`

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service#getPrettyFormat
>
> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service#getrawformat

```
// Log an XML document in human-readable form.
 var xml = '<root><a><b>Text!</b><b>More text!</b></a></root>';
 var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
 var output = XmlService.getPrettyFormat()
     .format(document);
 Logger.log(output);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Didn't realize I needed a Format object. Thanks!